# How to include and use Laravel Layout in Wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress, laravel, laravel-blade

I have a site which was built using Laravel.
Then, I want to create a blog using wordpress which was included inside my laravel folder.

The structure was now:

```
LaravelSite
 - app
 - blog
   - wp-admin
   - wp-content
   - wp-includes
 - bootstrap
 - config
.........
```

Is it possible to include the layout in my app.blade.php to wordpress page-blog.php ?

I tried this on in page-blog.php

```
<?php

include get_home_path().'../resources/views/layouts/web.blade.php';
```

It just show me this text in the browser:

```
@include('layouts.header')
@yield('content')
@include('layouts.footer')
```

Is there any way for wordpress to read laravel blade templates/syntax?

Comment: https://laraveldaily.com/convert-wordpress-theme-laravel-blade/

Comment: probably easier to use Elementor to redesign your page , so it looks like the laravel version. I am guessing you will spend more hours on triying to convert.

Comment: Or shall I say, create a separate layout just for wordpress theme?
If i will to edit the layout in laravel, will also edit the layout in wordpress?
what u think?

Answer (score 0):

Wordpress does not have integrated Blade template engine, you need to add it to your Theme manually
You can use [BladeOne](https://github.com/EFTEC/BladeOne) Git package for that. You just need to implement into Theme and all HTML need to be displayed through Blade package, like doc said

```
use eftec\bladeone\BladeOne;

$views = __DIR__ . '/views';
$cache = __DIR__ . '/cache';
$blade = new BladeOne($views,$cache,BladeOne::MODE_DEBUG); // MODE_DEBUG allows to pinpoint troubles.
echo $blade->run("hello",array("variable1"=>"value1")); // it calls /views/hello.blade.php
```

You just adjust paths to your template files.

If you can change the whole Wordpress Theme, there are a couple of Blade WP Themes who have already integrated Blade template engine